# Tkinter. When I input non-English, The Text widget is little bit weird

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a Application to chat. So Many parts had made.

While I make a part of inputting text, I met a Problem.

[image]

Can you see difference? This Problem only occurs Non-English Letter. This Problem don't obstruct To  chat. But For perfected program, I want to solve this problem.

Code is here.

```py
class chat(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,parent,*args,**kw):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,parent,*args,**kw)
        self.iconbitmap(default=r"./img/favicon.ico")
        self.parent = parent
        self.title("TEMP")
        self.geometry("400x500+%s+%s"%(str(int(int(self.winfo_screenwidth())/2)+rd.randrange(1,200)),str(int(int(self.winfo_screenmmheight() )/2)+rd.randrange(1,200))))

        self.top = tk.Frame(self,bg=ToRGB((220,220,220)),height = 80,bd=0)
        self.top.pack(side='top',fill='x')

        self.chatFrame = List(self)
        self.chatFrame.pack(side='top',fill='both',expand = True)
        self.chatFrame.canvas.configure(bg = ToRGB((220,220,220)))
        self.chatFrame.interior.config(bg = ToRGB((220,220,220)))

        self.inputFrame = tk.Frame(self,bg='white')
        self.inputFrame.pack(fill='x',side= 'top')

        self.inputText = tk.Text(self.inputFrame,height = 5,bd = 0,font=("맑은 고딕",11))
        self.inputText.pack(fill='both',anchor='c',padx = 5, pady = 5)

root = tk.Tk()
root.iconify()
app = chat(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[Problem2]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried other font-family?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Thank you sir. I found defalut set font. remove gap of font style. but background where typed position is still remain. do you know about this? [ I add picture, related this problem]

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Nearoo I want to remove white background [Problem2]

Answer (score 0):

I solve this Problem. Catch a system default font.

you can use variety font in Tkinter. It can check below code

```py
# Python 3.8
from tkinter import Tk, font
root = Tk()
a = font.families()
print(a)
```

and check what is your computer default font.

This Problem only occurs korean. I can't check other language. But maybe occurs.

Thank you post person commented !

But [Problem2] isn't solved. If I solve the problem. I post too.